# MySQL Trigger delete whole table instead of one Entry

Tags: mysql, triggers, subquery

I have two tables t1 (alternativeRoute) & t2 (alternativeRoute_addressInformation).

The challenge is, that if in T2 all entries with the same ID are deleted (All in one delete query or in succession), then the entry in T1 should also be deleted.

To do so I have created a SQL query, which works perfect if I run it by hand after deleting the entries from t2 with the same ID.

```
DELETE FROM traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute WHERE altRoute_id NOT IN (
SELECT distinct traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation.altRoute_id
FROM traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation);
```

But I want to perform that action automatically, therefore I decided to create a Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER clear_traffic_alternativeRoute
AFTER DELETE ON traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute WHERE altRoute_id NOT IN (
SELECT distinct    'traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation.altRoute_id'
FROM traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation);
END; $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Now the issue:
The trigger is fired, but instead of just deleting the entry from t1, all entries from both tables are deleted.

Does anyone have an idea why this code doesn´t work when using Triggers?

Test data:

T1:

```
INSERT INTO `traffic_alternativeRoute` (`info_id`, `altRoute_id`, `altRoute_desc`) VALUES
(66, 63, '');
INSERT INTO `traffic_alternativeRoute` (`info_id`, `altRoute_id`, `altRoute_desc`) VALUES
(66, 64, '');
```

T2:

```
INSERT INTO `traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation` (`altRoute_id`, altRouteAddress_id`, `altRoute_address`, `altRoute_address_houseNumber`, `altRoute_locality`, `altRoute_postal_code`, `altRoute_order_number`, `altRoute_pos_lat`, `altRoute_pos_lng`) VALUES
(63, 249, 'Kölner Straße', 445, 'Kürten', '51515', 1, 51.03150342683682, 7.209327220916748),
(63, 250, 'Kölner Straße', 488, 'Kürten', '51515', 2, 51.02742788461119, 7.205550670623779),
(64, 251, 'Engelsgasse', 14, 'Kürten', '51515', 3, 51.02900686236984, 7.199242115020752),
(64, 252, 'Cliev', 5, 'Kürten', '51515', 4, 51.03193525137229, 7.20728874206543);
```

Expected result:

After both entries with ID 64 are deleted, T1 should only contain the entry with ID 63.

EDIT:

One thing I haven´t said and also haven´t in mind anymore, is that I have an ON CASCADE on T1. Could that be part of the problem?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `traffic`.`traffic_alternativeRoute` (
  `info_id` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_desc` VARCHAR(256) NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`altRoute_id`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_info_id_idx` (`info_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_info_id`
   FOREIGN KEY (`info_id`)
   REFERENCES `traffic`.`traffic_info` (`info_id`)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
 ENGINE = InnoDB
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS   `traffic`.`traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation` (
  `altRoute_id` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRouteAddress_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_address` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_address_houseNumber` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_locality` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_postal_code` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_order_number` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_pos_lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `altRoute_pos_lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`altRouteAddress_id`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_altRoute_id_idx` (`altRoute_id` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_altRoute_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`altRoute_id`)
    REFERENCES `traffic`.`traffic_alternativeRoute` (`altRoute_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

And here the entrie DB - ERD, hope that helps:

[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QVMe.png)

Comment: Can you post some test data and results you expect?

Comment: Does your `DELETE` works correctly when run individually(separately).
Or `DISTINCT` might be conflicting.

Comment: Try single ID delete first via this procedure0

Comment: If I just run the DELETE with id = 63, it works. Also tested the Trigger without the DISTINCT, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use a subquery? You can accomplish what you need with a trigger as follows:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `clear_traffic_alternativeRoute`
  AFTER DELETE ON `traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  /*
  DELETE FROM traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute WHERE altRoute_id NOT IN (
  SELECT distinct 'traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation.altRoute_id'
  FROM traffic.traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation);
  */
  DELETE FROM `traffic_alternativeRoute`
  WHERE `altRoute_id` NOT IN (OLD.`altRoute_id`);
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a81b8e/1)</kbd>

Comment: I tested your version of the trigger, but it is still not working. All entries from t2 (alternativeRoute_addressInformation) are deleted (also entries with another id). Positive is that it works correct for T1 (alternativeRoute) now.

Comment: @Dev0x: Did you see the [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a81b8e/1)? Can you show your `DELETE` statement? Can we see the structure of your tables?.

Comment: I´ve added the create table queries to the main post! Currently I´m deleting the entries by hand via phpMyAdmin, for example: DELETE FROM `traffic`.`traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation` WHERE `traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation`.`altRouteAddress_id` = 274. Is that what you asked for?

Comment: @Dev0x: `ON DELETE CASCADE` has influence on behavior, of course.

Comment: But the CASCADE isn´t fired, or? We delete all entries from t2 and then delete the entrie from t1. But the cascade is fired, If the entry from t1 is deleted. So in order to this, the cascade should perform nothing, cause the entries are already removed. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Hm I´m a bit confused now and not sure how to go further. I decided to add the cascade, because the entries from t2 must be deleted If the entry of T1 is deleted! Should I also try to solve this with another trigger?

Comment: @Dev0x: The `ON DELETE CASCADE` is triggered, so all the data in `traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation` table are eliminated.

Comment: @Dev0x: `DELETE FROM \`traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation\`
WHERE \`altRoute_id\` = 63; -- Delete rows from the table \`traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation\``. `DELETE FROM \`traffic_alternativeRoute\`
WHERE \`altRoute_id\` NOT IN (OLD.\`altRoute_id\`); -- Delete rows from the table \`traffic_alternativeRoute\`` and `ON DELETE CASCADE` delete records in the table`traffic_alternativeRoute_addressInformation`.